# Should my web app upload pictures to a cloud storage by frontend or backend?

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, web-applications, cloud-storage

I'm building a web app in which people can upload pictures for a user profile and for other things). I'm using node js and express in the back end and Angular 2 for the front end.
Which way would be more professional to store uploaded pictures in a cloud storage as firebase?
Save the uploaded pictures with my front end or save them with my back end?
Thank you for your opinion!

Comment: Assuming you can do both securely, which costs more, uploading from client to FIRStorage or from your Server to FIRStorage?  What are your bandwidth charges?

Answer (score 2):

I don't actually think grabbing stuff from users without serious scrutiny to make sure it's really what you required from the user before getting them into your secure space is a good idea.
 Probably you need to check and be sure and if checking with the frontend is sufficient then it's your choice. 
Technical I suggest that you should validate things first using a secure backend language.

Answer (score 0):

For me there is no real differences here. But I just want to point out that you should never trust that images uploaded by users are safe.

I would upload them using your back-end because you might want to check if the images are really images and not some code hidden in jpg or to ensure a custom limit size for exemple.